# Cannot mount USB drive with "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error message

Tags: drivers, usb, 15.04

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

    lsblk
        sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
        ├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
        ├─sda2   8:2    0 150,3G  0 part 
        ├─sda3   8:3    0 558,5G  0 part 
        ├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
        ├─sda5   8:5    0 220,7G  0 part /
        └─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
        sdb      8:16   1   7,5G  0 disk 
        └─sdb1   8:17   1   7,5G  0 part 
        sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

And when I try

```
 mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

With `dmesg -tail`

```
dmesg | tail
[ 1059.082039] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1059.109149] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 1060.081502] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 8GB    8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 1060.081841] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1060.083326] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.02 GB/7.47 GiB)
[ 1060.085260] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1060.085264] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 1060.086416] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1060.092027]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1060.096224] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: JetFlash Transcend 8GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8028MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      131kB  8028MB  8028MB  primary
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The USB drive seems to be partitioned. Do not mount the device directly, but the partition `/dev/sdb1` instead:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Comment: No,the same as before!
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,

Comment: You might be missing support for the file system in use. How is the partition formatted? You should be able to get some more information with `parted /dev/sdb`, then run the `p` command (`p` as in "print").

Comment: W95 FAT32 is partition type

Comment: Try enfording FAT32 as file system: `mount -t msdos /dev/sdb1 /mnt`. If this still doesn't work, look at the `dmesg` output if any error message appears while mounting the partition.

Comment: dmesg
[ 3901.417474] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 3901.417480] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 3933.887955] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 3933.887963] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem

Comment: The file system seems broken. If you don't have any important files on that drive, considering reformatting. You might be able to use `fsck` to repair the file system and/or use some data recovery tools to recover files. If there's anything important on it, make sure to create a full image (for example using `dd`) before doing any work with the broken file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not have important files on disk.

Comment: Start with `sudo file -s /dev/sdb1` to do a low-level query. (`man file`).

Comment: @waltinator
/dev/sdb1: data

Comment: @Jean Erat : thanks, adding the `-t msdos` option did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

## Different Fault Causes this Error:

In addition to trying to mount a disk instead of a partition (see accepted answer), there's another problem which causes the same error to be puked:

***Attempting to mount a partition without a filesystem.***

In below example, please substitute the ***X*** in "/dev/sd***X***1" with your own disk designation and the "***1***" with the partition number you want to format with the filesystem.

## Error:

I was indeed mounting a partition and not an entire disk as was the case with the OP's error when I executed:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdX1 /media/userName
```

but nonetheless received the same error:

> "*mount: /media/userName: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
> /dev/sdX1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error*"

## Diagnostics:

I checked the filesystem type on the partition against the one I was specifying in the mount command:

```
df -Th /dev/sdX1
```

This returned `devtmpfs`; clearly this was not correct.

## Solution:

Format the partition with a filesystem and remount:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX1

sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdX1 /media/userName
```

The mount now succeeds.

If you execute

```
df -Th /dev/sdX1
```

the FS Type now reports "*vfat*"

## Conclusion:

I had a Homer Simpson moment. I had partitioned the disk but got called away before  I laid down a filesystem on the new partition. Thus, of course the `mount` command failed.

D'Oh!

Answer (score 1):

Since the drive was formatted in `NTFS`, reinstalling `ntfs-3g` fixed the issue for me.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ntfs-3g
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your udev rules for usb_modeswitch include your USB. Here is an example:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive

gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/ 40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

Add a new rule based upon the information you found in lusb:

```
#Generic USB
ATTR{idVendor}=="058f", ATTR{idProduct}=="6387", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

Unplug and replug USB, it should now show up as read-write.

Format the USB, add a new partition table as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Basically in my instance I had not formatted it at all. (I wanted exfat, but any format will probably do). It was just empty unformatted space. Take it to your disk manager window, or use the terminal, to place a format into the drive (example: fat32). then the computer can figure out what to do and can place data to or pull it from the drive. Also as an aside, if the drive is or recently was once bootable, try totally ERASING/FORMATTING the drive. When I say that I mean writing zeroes over all the data, totally obliterating it. Deleting usually means erasing the file names and such so it is "lost" and would be eventually overwritten, but can be recovered if you do it soon enough. Just erase, totally wipe, format the usb. These are interchangeable terms to some extent in this context. The drive which was once bootable may have been set to read only or write only or some such control - because its job was to boot your computer and to take it over essentially. It was set to write, essentially, inward onto your machine. So you may need to take the step to wipe it (forcibly) to make sure it can receive new data. May need to use higher authority (sudo).

Comment: Can you provide details on how to achieve the end state, such as specific terminal commands?  Is a total erasure necessary after partitioning?  If so, why?

Comment: @Damian T You really think the OP will answer on a 6 year old question?

Comment: @David The comment was to libertyrogue who posted the answer yesterday, not to OP.

Answer (score -1):

If you have reached here from Google, it's probably because the journal entries in your disk are wrong.
Check and fix your disk by

e2fsck -y -f -v -C 0 '/dev/sda1'

replace /dev/sda1 with your drive