# USB stick formated on an android tv not mounting kubuntu

Tags: gnome, usb, mount, kubuntu

I am trying to view all the files on a USB that was formated and mounted on an android tv it appears in gnome disks but it won't appear in removable devices tab or in discover and i need to mount it thanks in advanced.

Comment: run `lsblk` command to detect USB and then `mount /dev/<device-name> <mount-point>`

Comment: @sarru1291 when i run it i get this **mount: /media/usbstick: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/703183/cannot-mount-usb-drive-with-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error-me

read its comment hope it can help